# How to authenticate on a users that were made using ASP.NET Forms Authentication

Tags: asp.net, rest, authentication

My company maintains a legacy ASP.NET webforms application which uses Forms Authentication for access to the site. We are looking to build a mobile application which would utilize a stateless REST API with token based access. The problem is that the user's passwords were generated on the site and are hashed in the User database. I need a way to authenticate against those hashed passwords by somehow accessing the Forms Authentication's "authenticate" method or build some adapter/middlewear to broker the exchange.

We have done much research on this problem and haven't found any viable solutions as of yet. Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ValidateUser for that. It returns a bool. You can then use it in an webservice or api that accepts the two parameters as QueryString.

```
bool IsValidLogin = Membership.ValidateUser("UserName", "PassWord")
```